# Converting Python code to a TensorFlow program

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to convert the following Python code to a TensorFlow program but unable to access/modify matrix elements (I am running the code on Jupiter notebook).

```
edges = np.matrix('0 0 0 1; 0 0 1 0; 1 0 0 0; 0 0 1 0')
mat1 = np.matrix('0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0')
for i in range(0,4):    
  for j in range(0,4):
    if edges[i,j]==1 or (edges[i,0]==1 and edges[0,j]==1):
        mat1[i,j]=1
    else:
        mat1[i,j]=1            
print(mat1)
```

Please help with the code, so I may be able to run it using TensorFlow.

Comment: It's unclear what kind of help you expect, but *Stack Overflow* isn't the place to get software written for free.

Comment: Thank you @Borodin. I want to modify the matrix (mat1) entries but the indexing is not working in tensorflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there seems to be a mistake in your code. Both `if` and `else` conditions set your `mat1[i,j]` to `1`... Supposing your code is actually:

```python
for i in range(0,4):
  for j in range(0,4):
    if edges[i,j]==1 or (edges[i,0]==1 and edges[0,j]==1):
        mat1[i,j]=1
```

Then a Tensorflow solution is:

```python
import tensorflow as tf

edges = tf.constant([[0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=tf.int32)
mat1 = tf.zeros((4, 4), dtype=tf.int32)

# Building the edge condition matrix:
edges_bool = tf.equal(edges, 1)  # edges[:, :] == 1

edges_cond_i = edges_bool[:, 0]  # edges[:, 0] == 1
edges_cond_i = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(edges_cond_i, 1), (1, 4))
edges_cond_j = edges_bool[0, :]  # edges[0, :] == 1
edges_cond_j = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(edges_cond_j, 0), (4, 1))
edges_cond_ij = tf.logical_and(edges_cond_i, edges_cond_j)  
# edges[:, 0] == 1 and edges[0, :] == 1
edges_cond = tf.logical_or(edges_bool, edges_cond_ij)  
# edges[:, :] == 1 or (edges[:, 0] == 1 and edges[0, :] == 1)

# Applying the condition to mat1:
ones = tf.ones((4, 4), dtype=tf.int32)
mat1 = tf.where(edges_cond, ones, mat1)

# Displaying results:
with tf.device('/cpu:0'), tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run(mat1)
    print(res)
# [[0 0 0 1]
#  [0 0 1 0]
#  [1 0 0 1]
#  [0 0 1 0]]
```

Comment: Is there any way to manually input the entries of matrix 'edges' during runtime of code, in tensorflow?

Comment: Check [`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder).

Comment: I have a functional command on Python and want to learn tensorflow programming. Any recommendations?